# android facebookshare dialog does not show pre populated text in share dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer, android-facebook, facebook-share

In my Android application I want to share text message using Facebook share dialog screen with pre populated text but I get only share dialog without pre populated text. For example I want to post the text "User wants this pop up..." but the Facebook share dialog does not show my message in the dialog.

My question is what should I need to get share dialog with my pre populated text?

I have tried the following code:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new 
FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(FShareActivity.this)
                        .setLink(msg_link)
                        .setCaption(msg_caption)
                        .setDescription(msg_description) // msg_description should be shown in share dialog screen & it is my pre populated text.
                        .setName(msg_name).build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

and also tried this method also

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", msg_name);
params.putString("caption", msg_caption);
params.putString("description", msg_caption);
params.putString("link", msg_link);
WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
            FacebookException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                  // success
                } else {
                    // fail
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .build();
feedDialog.show();
```

Please let me know Is it possible to show pre populated text in share dialog screen? if yes Please tell me what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Setting description on the ShareDialogBuilder won't prefill the actual message which the user will be sharing. Setting description only sets the description of URL to be shared and adds it to the attachment shown in the dialog. It won't pre fill the user text.

It's against Facebook's policy to prefill user messages.

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>   parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/